# In rails Processing 45k of database records using workling without affecting server performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cpu-usage, workling

In my rails app, I use a worker process to scan 45k database records once in 6 hours and send out mails if certain condition is met. This causes the server CPU/Load to spike when the worker is processing. As a result of which other server request gets a performance hit. I tried using find_in_batch to retrieve 1000 records at a time and do the processing. But the CPU utilization is still at the peak level. No big difference i was able to see. Is there any way to handle this , so the CPU utilization doesn't hit the max limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddling with the process priority level using `nice` is one way to do it, but another is to tell your app to chill out a little bit now and then using the `sleep` or `select` command:

```
while (doing_stuff)
  do_stuff

  # Take a break for 0.2 seconds
  select(nil, nil, nil, 0.2)
end
```

The `select` call will block for a brief period of time allowing other tasks on the system to run freely. The higher you set this value the slower your job will run, but the lower the impact on the CPU load level.

Comment: This is a poor use of resources. Your app might run during a time where there is no contention for the CPU, in which case it needlessly spends 0.2 seconds doing nothing for each record in the database.

Comment: You could always expand on this to set the delay time to be variable depending on system load.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're invoking the job via cron and `script/runner`. You might try lowering the priority of process with [`nice`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29):

```
nice -n 19 /usr/bin/ruby <path to your app>/script/runner <your script>
```

Comment: This won't affect CPU load, but it will mean that other processes have a higher priority. Unfortunately database calls are all considered equal so a lot of query activity will have a knock-on effect on any production system attached to it.

Comment: I am using rufus scheduler to scheduler worker process to run in regular interval